# Превращение блоков в друг друга

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Изначально на странице отображается только блок red. Как сделать чтобы при наведении на блок red он превращался в блок green, а при отведении - обратно в red. Без использования toggleClass и вообще без манипулирования классами,потому что эти блоки - с разным контентом.

```
<div class="red">Красные поля</div>
<div class="green">Зеленые поля</div>
```

Comment: в одну сторону только можно – `.red:hover ~ .green { color:red }`; но кажется я вас совсем не так понял. Если понять как написано, то вообще никак никак совсем

Comment: Поясните, что значит **блок red он превращался в блок green, а при отведении - обратно в red**.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что при наведении на red он должен скрыться и отобразиться green

Comment: если хотите - покажу красивый эффект при наведении

Comment: Давайте покажите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот например. Еще кое что, CSS это такая вещь с которой приходится импровизировать, это не C++ где нужно что-бы было все структурировано.

```css
.card *
{
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  position:absolute;
}
.card 
{
  position:relative;
}

.red 
{
  background:red;
  color: white;
}

.green 
{
  background:green;
  color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.card:hover .red
{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.card:hover .green
{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class = "card">
  <div class = "red">Красные поля</div>
  <div class = "green">Зеленые поля</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

В каком смысле превращался? Именно принимал класс другого блока? Это уже js.

```
document.getElementById(".red").className = 'green';
```

Если же нужно чтобы блок red принимал свойства green, можно например так

```
.red:hover {
 // Свойста //
}
```